# Finding a value in a tuple that is not in a list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple and a list of tuples. The tuple is titled talent and is a tuple from a JSON parse, it contains data about a specific student and the books that student has checked out (book-id-list) and the teachers that the books belong to (teacher-id-list). The list of tuples is titled data and it is a list of tuples from a SQL query from a database, this contains data about a book id and the id of the teacher that owns the book. Here is an example of the organization of my tuples:

```
Student (tuple)
  00000 (dictionary)
      'book-id-list' = ['10123', '10198', '20156'] (list)
            0 = '10123'(string)
            1 = '10198'(string)
            2 = '20156'(string)
      'teacher-id-list' = {id: '7834abc&a', 'teacher-id': '4567'}, {id: '8834vfs&a', 'teacher-id': 
      '1234'} (list)
            0 = {id: '7834abc&a', 'teacher-id': '4567'} (dictionary)
               'teacher-id'='4567' (string)
            1 = {id: '8834vfs&a', 'teacher-id':'1234'} (dictionary)
               'teacher-id'='1234'(string)
```

```
Data (list)
  000000 (tuple)
     0 = 10123 (this is the book id) (integer)
     1 = 1234 (this is the teacher id) (integer)
```

**Objective 1**
Check if a book id in Student book-id-list is not present in any data[x][0]. Also check if a teacher id in Student teacher-id-list is not present in any data[x][1]. Print out those values.

This is what I have so far:

```
for x in Student:
    for y in data:
        if y[0] in x['book-id-list']:
            print('Success')
```

I was thinking that I could count the number of success that I return but, it just runs and returns nothing. My goal is to actually return any values that are missing as I said above. Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: int and str are never considered equal, use `str` to convert int to str and then check if this string is in the list of strings.

Comment: is this python?

Comment: Please include a small example for what `Student` and `data` are like

Comment: Yes it is Python and I have the Student and data examples in the first two code blocks

Comment: Could type it out in python format then, since at least Im not exactly sure what kind of structure it should be in python?